# Filling a gap between drywall and stair stringer

Tags: drywall, paint, stairs, caulking

I was planning to remove the old ugly cove moulding on my stair stringers. 30 years of lazy paints jobs have left it in a very bad state.

[image: Cove moulding]

My initial plan was to just sand the stringer and wall, get them all cleaned and patched up and looking good, then caulk the right angle where they meet.

However, when I started prying off the moulding I discovered the drywall doesn't actually meet the stringer. It's about half an inch short.

[image: Gap above stair stringer]

[image: Another angle of the gap]

Is there any durable, secure way to fill this void and achieve the clean finished angle I was hoping for, or am I going to have to resort to covering it back up with quarter round?

Comment: This is what moldings were created for...

Answer (score 2):

Wow!  If that's your most important home improvement project, you're really lucky.

Even if the drywall came all the way down to the stringer and you sanded everything smooth and caulked the corner, I don't think you'd be happy with it. Caulk is very hard to apply right. It looks easy but to get it perfectly smooth and even, Well if you ever caulked a tub or backsplash you know it's not. You could try sanding everything smooth, filling in the crack with drywall mud and taping the drywall down to the stringer. That will probably give you the sharp angle you're looking for. Remember, sharp angles dent really easy.

Personally, I think a new piece of quarter round would look better. Good luck and stay safe out there.